# How to find the install location and GUID of 3rd party application whose GUID changes for every installation using install shield?

Tags: installshield, regedit, installscript, installshield-2011

I know the application name and trying to find the install location and GUID of the application using install shield.

I found the application registry values(like DisplayName, InstallLocation, UninstallString, etc) in following location manually: 
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{GUID}

But GUID of the application is different in each client machine, So I'm not able to hard code the registry path to get these values using following function.
  RegDBGetKeyValueEx();

Can we able to find the GUID of the application if we know the application name?

Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to answer without additional details as to how you might identify it manually; i.e. what *doesn't* change? For example, if it is MSI-based, and contains at least know component that doesn't change IDs, or its Uninstall key always contains something you can recognize, that could be leveraged.

Comment: Actually It's a 3rd party application, where I found only "Application name" is unique in all client machines and different GUID in all machines as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the Uninstall keys with code similar to the [RegDBQueryKey example](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/Default.htm#StartTopic=Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefRegDBQueryKey_example.htm):

```
#define UNINSTALLKEYPATH "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
listKeys = ListCreate(STRINGLIST);
RegDBQueryKey(UNINSTALLKEYPATH, REGDB_KEYS, listKeys);
```

And then you can iterate these keys looking for the appropriate value using code similar to the [ListGetNextItem example](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/Default.htm#StartTopic=Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefListGetNextItem_example.htm):

```
nResult = ListGetFirstItem(listKeys, sItem);
while (nResult != END_OF_LIST)
    RegDBGetKeyValueEx(UNINSTALLKEYPATH ^ sItem, ...); // check each key
    nResult = ListGetNextItem(listKeys, sItem);
endwhile;
```

Once you find it, you can leverage any other information in that key, or the name of the key itself. (Note: don't forget to destroy the list.)

If you know additional things about this setup, for instance if it's an MSI, there may be more direct approaches that leverage Windows Installer APIs.